# SQL how to return '0' if no row is found

Tags: sql, join, select

This is my sql:

```
select 
a.column1,
b.column2
from table1 a inner join table2 b
on a.column8 = b.column9
where b.column5 = '2018'
and b.column6 = 'G1';
```

Problem: a.column1/table1 holds 250000 rows, and b.column2/table2 holds only 153000 rows.
How can this sql be changed to reply 250000 rows, and print '0' in b.column2/table2 when row is not found?

Comment: You want a left join not an inner join

Comment: After left join as @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned, you can use case when to print the value in the format you need: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp or use COALESCE function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `left join`:

```
select t1.column1, coalesce(t2.column2, 0) column2
from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2
    on  t2.column9 = t2.column1
    and t1.column5 = '2018'
    and t1.column6 = 'G1';
```

This selects all rows from `table1`, even if there is no match in `table2` - in which case output column `t2.column2` will be `null`, which we we turn to `'0'` with `coalesce()`.

PS: if `t2.column2` is not a number but a string, then use `coalesce(t2.column2, '0')` instead (note the single quotes).

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. This sql works just perfect. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN` :

```
SELECT T1.COL1, COALESCE(T2.COL2, 0)
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN
     T2
     ON T1.COL8 = T2.COL9 AND T2.COL5 = 2018 AND T2.COL6 = 'G1'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
a.column1,
COALESCE ( b.column2, 0)
from table1 a LEFT join table2 b
on a.column8 = b.column9
where b.column5 = '2018'
and b.column6 = 'G1';
```

You need to use `LEFT JOIN`
`coalesce` will replace NULL values with `0`

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping out. The sql works perfect - after I changed the "when" into a "and"... :)